# Guice cannot find a suitable constructor: @Inject class Patient(v1:C1) {}

Tags: scala, guice

How to make it work?
I know that short questions aren't appreciated. But I have nothing to add this time.

update 1: As workaround I've made the constructor auxiliary, but I don't like this as it adds quite a lot of burden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Patient @Inject() (v1:C1) {}
```

Just found it here: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/3388